# onClick JavaScript function inside HTML-form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I cant't get a simple button to work when it is inside a html form, while it works normally when not inside a html form.

This code doesn't work:

```
<head>
    <script langauge="JavaScript">
    function reset(){
        alert('test')
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="nyform">
    <input type="button" value="Reset" onClick="reset()">
</form>
</body>
```

While this one does:

```
<head>
    <script langauge="JavaScript">
    function reset(){
        alert('test')
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="Reset" onClick="reset()">
</body>
```

What is the reason for this, and how can I correct it?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe change your function's name.. I am thinking that reset may be a reserved word.

Comment: He is right, reset() is a JavaScript-function which clears/empties form fields. The second sample just works because no form-tag is wrapped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the function `reset()` has a different meaning inside a form, and your custom function doesn't override it. I changed the function name to `reset2` and it all worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now, I will give you credit when the time limit has passed :)